# How to get Bitgo js receiving wallet address from wallet id

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get the receiving wallet address from wallet Id , so that i can send btc to that particular address.But unable to get the receiving address.My code is like:

```
let walletId = ''; // here is my wallet Id

bitgo.coin('tbtc').wallets().get({ id: walletId })
.then(function(wallet)
{
  // print the wallet
 console.dir(wallet); // here i get whole array of wallet
});
```

**I am unable to get the receiveAddress from this array, I tried it this way:**

> wallet.receiveAddress() // here i got error receiveAddress is not a function
>   wallet.receiveAddress.address // error for this undefined address

Answer (score 0):

We can get it by using :

```
bitgo.coin('tbtc').wallets().get({ id: walletId })
.then(function(wallet)
{
  // print the wallet
 console.dir(wallet.receiveAddress());
});
```

**console.dir(wallet.receiveAddress());** // this works well